# Dojo infinite bounce animation

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I need to make this css3 animation using Dojo, but I'm not getting the desired result. The arrow should bounce when its hovered. Simiilar to this http://codepen.io/dodozhang21/pen/siKtp but horizontal.
HTML:

```
            <a href="#" class="uiAnimatedArrow" title="Buying a Home">
                <!-- -->
                <span>
                    <i data-copy="Learn More"><b></b></i>
                    Buying a Home
                </span>
            </a>
```

CSS:

```
a.uiAnimatedArrow i b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 9px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: -6px 0 0 0;
  content: '';
  background: url("/assets/images/icons/arrow-right-black.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
  right: 13px;
}

  a.uiAnimatedArrow span:hover i b {
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
  -ms-animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
  -o-animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
  animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: whats the desired effect? also, it would help if you provided the full code (or a jsfiddle) so that one could provide a solution that doesn't require writing a test project. (the issue might be elsewhere too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that in Dojo you'll have to use `dojo/_base/fx` to animate the `right` property. However, you cannot do this in a single animation, because there are multiple keyframes defined. So, you'll have to split it up in the following cases (if you want it similar to the given Codepen):

```
0%  0
20% 0
40% -30
50% 0
60% -15
80% 0
```

So, we'll need 4 separate animations, from 20% to 40%, from 40% to 50%, from 50% to 60% and from 60% to 80%.

Using `dojo/_base/fx` you can make something like this:

```
function frame40(node) {
    return fx.animateProperty({
        node: node,
        properties: {
            right: {
                start: 0,
                end: 30
            }
        },
        delay: 800,
        duration: 200,
        easing: easing.quadInOut
    });
}

function frame50(node) {
    return fx.animateProperty({
        node: node,
        properties: {
            right: {
                start: 30,
                end: 0
            }
        },
        duration: 200,
        easing: easing.quadInOut
    });
}

function frame60(node) {
    return fx.animateProperty({
        node: node,
        properties: {
            right: {
                start: 0,
                end: 15
            }
        },
        duration: 200,
        easing: easing.quadInOut
    });
}

function frame80(node) {
    return fx.animateProperty({
        node: node,
        properties: {
            right: {
                start: 15,
                end: 0
            }
        },
        duration: 400,
        easing: easing.quadInOut
    });
}
```

In this case I'm animating the `right` property for a given `duration`. The duration is based on the keyframe percentage * the total animation (`2s` in the Codepen).

I also added an `easing` property using `dojo/fx/easing` because otherwise it's just a linear animation which doesn't feel natural to me.

To invoke the animation, we need to create two event listeners, a `mouseenter` listener and a `mouseleave` listener. In the `mouseenter` listener we will have to chain the animation and play it. To chain them, you can use the `dojo/fx::chain()` function. However, this only plays the animation once. To run it infinitely, we use the `setInterval()` function to repeat the animation every 2 seconds:

```
var interval, anim;
query(".arrow").on("mouseenter", function() {
    var node = this;
    var keyframes = function() {
        anim = coreFx.chain([
            frame40(node),
            frame50(node),
            frame60(node),
            frame80(node)
        ]).play();
    };
    interval = setInterval(keyframes, 2000);
    keyframes();
});
```

Now, in the `mouseleave` event handler we have to clear the interval and we have to stop the animation if it was playing. However, stopping the animation may cause the arrow to be stopped in "mid air", so we have to properly put it back to the right, you could do that with an animation as well:

```
query(".arrow").on("mouseleave", function() {
    if (interval != null) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    if (anim != null) {
        anim.stop();
        fx.animateProperty({
            node: this,
            properties: {
                right: 0
            },
            duration: 200,
            easing: easing.quadInOut
        }).play();
    }
});
```

That should be everything, you can check out the complete example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ro55btas/

Comment: Yes, I have those keyframes. But I need to do this animation via Dojo because IE9 does not support CSS3 animations/transitions.

Comment: There is a example of bounce animation in [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/fx/easing.html#id4) example, not sure how you will be adapting to your requirement

Comment: @TeodoraS.K, I updated my answer. It wasn't clear to me why you needed Dojo, but now I get it.